# Local testing without affecting backend

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking to import some resources into terraform but I would first like to test everything locally before making any changes to state in our backend.

ie. I would like to `check out` the current state, run `terraform import` locally and and see the changes of my plan without changing the backend state.

What I have been doing so far:

1. initialize using backend
2. comment out the backend block and run init again telling terraform to copy my previously found state
3. run my imports and terraform plan

Just wondering if there is a better approach? I've looked into `workspaces` but I don't want terraform to treat everything as new.

Thanks.

Comment: A plan won't make any changes. What's wrong with just running the plan? If you don't like the changes made by the import you can always remove them from the state with `terraform state rm`.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid making any changes to the actual backend state until the code is ready to be merged as it may interfere with other devs.

Comment: I've never used but you can try localstack to mimic was locally https://dev.to/mrwormhole/localstack-with-terraform-and-docker-for-running-aws-locally-3a6d